# How to calculate this energy for a given signal?

Tags: signal-analysis

So the question Im asking can be seen in the picture below.The d at the end of the question stands for the minimum euclidian distance.

Mostly I just want to know how to calculate the energy for each signal. I know how to calculate the energy efficiency between two constellations (10 * log(E1/E2)).
 [image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If your question really is how to calculate the energy of a given signal $x(t)$ then the answer is

$$E_x=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x(t)|^2dt\tag{1}$$

but I wonder if that is actually what you're asking, because it would have been very easy to find that formula.